# Github Push Error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413

Tags: git, github, git-tower

stupid issue with Github going on right now. I have a decent amount of changes (~120MB in size), when I attempt to push, this is what happens:

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've already done

`git config http.postBuffer 524288000`, so that doesn't seem to be the issue. What could it be?

Comment: For future visitors, if you are getting `HTTP code = 0`, GitHub is down, like yesterday.

Comment: I got `HTTP code = 0` when my proxy was blocking. My http proxy works with github, but the https doesn't for my corporate proxy. I think my HTTPS proxy forces NTLM, while the HTTP accepts BASIC. I changed the repo origin URL from https to http and it worked for me. `git remote set-url origin http://github.com/GitUserName/GitRepoName.git`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I figured it out!!! Of course I would right after I hit post!

I had the repo set to use the HTTPS url, I changed it to the SSH address, and everything resumed working flawlessly.

Comment: That's not the reason for the problem. That's just a workaround. I want to know why its failing on https.

Comment: For me ssh is not an option. So in case you are in the same situation @ZincX, see my answer above.

Comment: This is just a work around. Tinou's answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: how did you changed that?

Comment: Many people probably don't have access to their web server so this information is much appreciated!

Comment: that damned http buffered packet!!

Answer (score 277):

If you get error 413, then the issue doesn't lie with git but *with your web server*.
It's your web server that is blocking big upload files.

### Solution for nginx

Just load your `nginx.conf` and add `client_max_body_size 50m;` ( changing the value to your needs ) in the http block.

Reload nginx to accept the new config by executing `sudo service nginx reload` and try again to push your commit over http.

### Solution for Apache

In your `httpd.conf` add `LimitRequestBody 52428800`  ( changing the value to your needs ) inside a `<Directory />` block. Doing this you can limit the request of the whole server filesystem, just a single Virtual Host or a directory.

Comment: 50m wasn't enough for me, but this did solve my problem! Thanks!

Comment: I had to do that also on an intermediate nginx proxy.

Comment: What if your not using Nginx?

Comment: any solution for gitlab omnibus installation ..? latest version 12.1

Comment: After much searching, cussing, and crying. ( in that order ) I found that the embeded config file was located at:   /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf

Comment: I am working on Windows10 and I don't use any web-server. Would you please advice how to fix this issue ?

Comment: This same my life <3

Comment: If your web-server is behind a proxy, the proxy will also need this solution applied.

Comment: What if the total git repo size is larger than 2GB and the max limit of Apache is 2GB?

Comment: This field can also be located at /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite  config file - so need to check both : nginx.conf and yoursite settings

Answer (score 39):

command to change the remote url ( from https -> git@... ) is something like this

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:GitUserName/GitRepoName.git
```

origin here is the name of my remote ( do git remote and what comes out is your origin ).

Comment: In case of bitbucket ('Clone' button) I had a problem when removed `ssh://` from `ssh://git@<bitbucket-repo>:<port>/dir/to/project.git` So be careful, guys!

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem but I was using a reverse proxy.

So I had to set

```
client_max_body_size 50m;
```

inside both configure files :

- on the gitlab nginx web server (as said inside the previous answers)
- **but also on the nginx reverse proxy hosted on the dedicated server.**

Comment: any solution for gitlab omnibus installation ..?

Comment: maybe take a look at omnibus/nginx conf : 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#inserting-custom-settings-into-the-nginx-config

Comment: Wanted to thank you for this solution, I had exactly this setup.

Answer (score 13):

If you are facing this issue while pushing changes in big size then run below command in terminal.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

See [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-779171796.html) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

I already had "HTTPS//" in the git URL yet faced this error.

All I did was to add option -u with push and it worked.

`git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 4):

For those who use **IIS 7** to host a git `http`/`https` endpoint:

You need to increase your `uploadReadAheadSize`.

Launch **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager**

1. Expand the Server field
2. Expand Sites
3. Select the site you want to make the modification for.
4. In the Features section, double click `Configuration Editor`
5. Under `Section` select: `system.webServer > serverRuntime`
6. Modify the `uploadReadAheadSize` section (The value must be between `0` and `2147483647`.)
7. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>
8. Restart the Website

Comment: To Restart the website I selected **Default Web Site** and on the right-hand side, under **Actions** there are **Stop** and **Start** buttons.

Comment: This fix was still required in IIS 10.

Comment: Changing uploadReadAheadSize does not work for me, changing "Maximum allowed content length" (IIS->Git Site->Features->Request Filtering->Edit Feature Setting) to a value larger than what size git wants to upload (in my case 39.28 MiB is larger than 30_000_000 bytes) helped. (git will show size of request in push command output)

Answer (score 2):

Do you use https links instead of ssh links? Because the https link is limited by the size of the upload of HttpServer (such as Apache, Ngnix), there is no such restriction when using ssh.

Use the following method to switch to the ssh link.

1. Open terminal.
2. Switch to your project's working directory.
3. Get the name of the remote repository

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/[user_name]/[project_name].git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/[user_name]/[project_name].git (push)
```

4. Modify the git address to ssh link.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:[user_name]/[project_name].git
```

If you determine the remote repository name, proceed directly to step 4.
Now, you can do the push operation happily.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs in 'libcurl', which is the underlying protocol for https upload. Solution is to somehow updgrade libcurl.
To get more details about the error, set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=306348908

Meaning of error, as per libcurl doc:
CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR (22)

This is returned if CURLOPT_FAILONERROR is set TRUE and the HTTP server returns an error code that is >= 400.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem when I try to clone a git repo in Linux machine.

the following URL is working for me in windows

```
http://swamy@git.swamy.com/scm/project/swamy-main.git
```

whereas the following URL works in Linux machine and it has https in URL

```
https://swamy@git.swamy.com/scm/project/swamy-main.git
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error (**error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413**) when I tried to push my initial commit to a new BitBucket repository. The error occurred for me because the BitBucket repo had **no master** branch. If you are using **SourceTree** you can create a master branch on the origin by pressing the **Git Flow button**.

Answer (score 1):

Need to change remote url to [ssh](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html) or https

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:laravel/laravel.git
```

or

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
```

Hope, this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using http connection, set http config as 1.1 would help.

`git config http.version HTTP/1.1`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (on Win XP), I updated the libcurl-4.dll file in my Git bin directory to the SSL version from http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?download=curl_DLL_ONLY.7z (renaming to libcurl4.dll). All working ok now.

Answer (score 0):

https clone of gists fails (ssh works, see below):

```
12:00 jean@laptop:~/tmp$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://gist.github.com/123456.git username
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/jean/tmp/username/.git/
* Couldn't find host gist.github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to gist.github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 192.30.252.142... * Connected to gist.github.com (192.30.252.142) port 443 (#0)
* found 141 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*        server certificate verification OK
*        common name: *.github.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: C=US,ST=California,L=San Francisco,O=GitHub\, Inc.,CN=*.github.com
*        start date: Mon, 30 Apr 2012 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: Wed, 09 Jul 2014 12:00:00 GMT
*        issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
*        compression: NULL
*        cipher: ARCFOUR-128
*        MAC: SHA1
> GET /123456.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.1
Host: gist.github.com
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: GitHub.com
< Date: Fri, 01 Nov 2013 05:00:51 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 178
< Location: https://gist.github.com/gist/123456.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Expire cleared
* Connection #0 to host gist.github.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://gist.github.com/gist/123456.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack'
* Couldn't find host gist.github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host gist.github.com
* Connected to gist.github.com (192.30.252.142) port 443 (#0)
> GET /gist/123456.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.1
Host: gist.github.com
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: GitHub.com
< Date: Fri, 01 Nov 2013 05:00:52 GMT
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
* Connection #0 to host gist.github.com left intact
* Couldn't find host gist.github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to gist.github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 192.30.252.142... * connected
* Connected to gist.github.com (192.30.252.142) port 443 (#0)
* found 141 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* SSL re-using session ID
*        server certificate verification OK
*        common name: *.github.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: C=US,ST=California,L=San Francisco,O=GitHub\, Inc.,CN=*.github.com
*        start date: Mon, 30 Apr 2012 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: Wed, 09 Jul 2014 12:00:00 GMT
*        issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
*        compression: NULL
*        cipher: ARCFOUR-128
*        MAC: SHA1
> POST /123456.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.1
Host: gist.github.com
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
Content-Length: 116

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: GitHub.com
< Date: Fri, 01 Nov 2013 05:00:53 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 178
< Location: https://gist.github.com/gist/123456.git/git-upload-pack
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host gist.github.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://gist.github.com/gist/123456.git/git-upload-pack'
* Violate RFC 2616/10.3.2 and switch from POST to GET
* Couldn't find host gist.github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host gist.github.com
* Connected to gist.github.com (192.30.252.142) port 443 (#0)
> GET /gist/123456.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.1
Host: gist.github.com
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result

* The requested URL returned error: 400
* Closing connection #0
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 400
```

This works: `git clone git@gist.github.com:123456.git`

Comment: The OP didn't ask about clone, but about push.

Comment: Well, the OP asked about communication with github. Why I responded with an answer about gists I have no idea though.

Comment: Hah, fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Was facing same issue.
In my case it was non-compatible GIT versions across multiple users who are accessing(pull/push) same project.

have just updated GIT version and updated the path on Android studio settings and its working fine for me.

Edit -

Git for Windows (1.9.5) having some problem, updating the same may helps.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue however it got resolved by cleaning up the git repository (Clean untracked files using "git clean").

Comment: when I do git clean it is showing this error:
 fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -i, -n, nor -f given; refusing to clean

Comment: for @Chandni and anyone who faces same error message  git helps you itself, try `git clean -i` for instance to start in interactive mode.

Comment: @seethrough - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when I used the https url to push to the remote master, I met the same proble, I changed it to the SSH address, and everything resumed working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by increasing the size in the following line nginx['client_max_body_size'] = 'Xm' in the file /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

X= your value. The default value is 250.

After updating the file, run the re-configure command gitlab-ctl reconfigure

Answer (score 0):

For those whose changes are not really huge in size and still getting this error.
I had the same error
`error: RPC failed; HTTP 413 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 413`
you know what saved the day?

`git pull --rebase`

There were changes on the remote repo that were not in my local repo and just a simple `rebase` solved the issue. Talk about misleading error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem equals, for me work this.

git config --global http.followRedirects true

git config --global http.postBuffer 1073741824

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?