# Git add folder and push

Tags: git

Currently I have those files in remote repository:

```
README 
run.bat 
MyCalories2
```

MyCalories2 is a folder that is empty but needs to have project files. The problem is that none of these files are saved in the repo.

I tried with `git add .` and also tried adding this folder from SourceTree but they are simply never uploaded to the remote repo.

```
$ git add .
$ git push -u origin master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

But it's not! How do I add the complete folder to git?

```
 ~/Dropbox/AndroidStudioProjects/test/xxx (master|MERGING)
$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'http://git.yyy.com': xxx
Password for 'http://yyy.com':
To http://git.yyy.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://yyy.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

This is latest error msg. Real URLs are masked with 'yyy'.

I tried all of these commands:

```
ls -la . MyCalories2

MyCalories2:
total 15
drwxr-xr-x    1 Jalle    Administ     4096 Jul 25 21:46 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 Jalle    Administ     4096 Jul 25 21:49 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 Jalle    Administ       64 Jul 16 19:59 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x    3 Jalle    Administ        0 Jul 25 14:37 .gradle
drwxr-xr-x   15 Jalle    Administ     4096 Jul 25 21:51 .idea
-rw-r--r--    1 Jalle    Administ      870 Jul 16 20:01 MyCalories2.iml
drwxr-xr-x    1 Jalle    Administ     4096 Jul 25 21:24 app
drwxr-xr-x    3 Jalle    Administ        0 Jul 25 14:37 build
-rw-r--r--    1 Jalle    Administ      452 Jul 24 21:33 build.gradle
drwxr-xr-x    3 Jalle    Administ        0 Jul 25 14:37 gradle
-rw-r--r--    1 Jalle    Administ      870 Jul 16 19:59 gradle.properties
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Jalle    Administ     5080 Jul 16 19:59 gradlew
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Jalle    Administ     2404 Jul 16 19:59 gradlew.bat
-rw-r--r--    1 Jalle    Administ      435 Jul 16 19:59 local.properties
drwxr-xr-x    5 Jalle    Administ        0 Jul 25 14:37 parseproj
-rw-r--r--    1 Jalle    Administ       16 Jul 16 19:59 settings.gradle


$ git --version
git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0

$ git pull
U       MyCalories2
M       run.bat
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.

$ git mergetool
Merging:
MyCalories2

Submodule merge conflict for 'MyCalories2':
  {local}: deleted
  {remote}: submodule commit 4bf1b974662b5b694f985ee93401227262fd3f26
Use (l)ocal or (r)emote, or (a)bort? l


$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'http://yyy.com': yyy
Password for 'http://yyy.com':
Counting objects: 245, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (215/215), done.
efrror: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 4136.00 KiB/s
Watal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (243/243), 1.29 MiB | 136.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 243 (delta 99), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

But why this error?

Here is my config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://git.yyy.com/My-Name/My-Name.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[http]
    postBuffer = 524288000
[remote "ssh"]
    url = My-Name@yyy.com:My-Name/My-Name.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/ssh/*
    pushurl = My-Name@yyy.com:My-Name/My-Name.git
```

Comment: Did you do a `git commit` after the add?

Comment: Might've been an idea to list that command too, since you carefully listed the others you ran. Your actual problem is that you're trying to add an *empty* folder. Don't think the original version of your question said that.

Comment: ITs NOT empty directory. Why should I do that . Please remove this tag from my post. I am talking about complete project that I need to update. Why should I ever worry about empty folder ?

Comment: Sorry, I read "folder that is empty" and assumed you meant "folder that is empty".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unclear and self-contradictory ("FOLDER THAT IS EMPTY" followed by a listing of extensive content in that folder) even after multiple edits by an OP who's long gone, last seen ~4 years ago.

Comment: Your problem is maybe related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489813/github-push-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-413).

Comment: hey, you miss `git commit` after `git add .` !!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now the issue at hand is a completely different one than originally...

From the output of `git mergetool` it's apparent that MyCalories2:

1. exists in the remote repository.
2. is actually a git [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) in the remote repository.

Most probably you should **not** just replace that submodule with your in-repository copy
of MyCalories2.

What you need to do is `git clone` a fresh copy of the repository, then copy the changes you want to commit (if any) from your old copy to the new copy. Then please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814351/1379556) for info about how to push changes in a submodule.

Comment: i updated question, those commands wont help either. STill cant add folder to repository

Comment: Looks odd, but you need to provide some more info. What does `ls -la . MyCalories2` and `git --version` say?

Answer (score 0):

Do with initially like

```
git init
```

and then if you are reading any file or folder then do with this command

```
git add <file/folder name>
```

or

if you are adding lot of files then `git add .` also enough to add all files at once

then commit the files

```
git commit -m "First commit"
```

then push to the branch like

```
git push
```

And the error message saying that the file up to date with repo so pull and rebase gonna work

```
git pull 

git rebase
```