# cvs2git migration with errors, no files on remote server

Tags: git, cvs2git

I'm trying to migrate a cvs repository to git (on a local Ubuntu system). The git-server runs on http://gitserver/

Everythink works fine. With `gitk --all` I can see all cvs commits that are migrated to git. But I can't push the files to my remote git-server!
If I try `git push -u origin master` then I get the error

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Without the `git checkout` I can't see any files, only .git folder. In my gitlab webview there I cant see any files...
What should I do next? Should I copy the .git folder to my remote gitserver manually via ssh? Should I copy all my project files to my local git folder? My repo folder has about 1.8 gb size

1.

```
mkdir cvs2svn-tmp
cd cvs2svn-tmp
cvs2git --blobfile=cvs2svn-tmp/git-blob.dat --dumpfile=cvs2svn-tmp/git-dump.dat --username=cvs2git --encoding=ISO-8859-1 /home/testuser/cvsroot
```

2.

```
mkdir myproject_test
cd myproject_test
git init

cd .git
```

3.

```
git fast-import --export-marks=/home/testuser/cvs2svn-tmp/git-marks.dat < /home/testuser/cvs2svn-tmp/git-blob.dat
git fast-import --import-marks=/home/testuser/cvs2svn-tmp/git-marks.dat < /home/testuser/cvs2svn-tmp/git-dump.dat
```

4.

```
git remote add origin http://gitserver/myproject/myproject_test.git
```

5.

```
cd ..
git checkout
```

6.

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Have you tested pushing a test Git repository (that wasn't CVS-migrated) to your server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489813/github-push-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-413

Comment: Ah!! Found a solution! I've added my ssh-key in gitlab und tried over ssh and it works now! Just changed the remote origin host from http to ssh