# Azure Web App Git Push Failure (RPC failed; result=56)

Tags: git, azure

I have been developing a web app on Microsoft Azure with a Git repository using Node.js and AngularJS.

It has been deploying successfully for the past few weeks and then today, I have added a small animation to the page using ng-show and @keyframes.
When attempting to push these changes to the git, I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\Azure\AlexH>git push origin master
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 49.24 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 6), reused 10 (delta 3)
efrror: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
atal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I have read that this was due to the HTTP post buffer limit so I have attempted the following, giving no improvement:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

I have also restarted the web app through the Azure Portal and retried the push, again giving no improvement.

I'd appreciate any help you can provide to resolve this.

Comment: Can you share your site name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Also, include the time of the deployment.

Comment: @DavidEbbo I've set up a dummy app called dummy112233. I last attempted a deployment at around 5pm I believe but I was trying it all afternoon ever since my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at last deployment (commit id starts with `4d00`), it seems it was successful. Could it be that for some reason the client disconnected (for some reason), but that the deployment is actually working fine?

Please try going to the deployment list in the portal, so check whether it all looks successful. I suspect it will.

Comment: The commit was still in my local repository so would not have shown up in the deployment as that id is for the previous push which worked. While looking at the git log on my computer, it attempted the git push again and it was successful. The only change I have made is that I am now on different WiFi since I have changed locations. What would cause this problem with other wifi hotspots?

Comment: Ah, you're right it failed so early that the server would not have started processing it. One thing I would try: try pushing the same repo from the 'bad' wifi to a GitHub repo, using https to match Azure (i.e. not using ssh). It it fails for it as well, then it may be some flakiness with that wifi.

Comment: Apologies for the delay but I have been doing some development at university through the eduroam student wifi (which is generally very fast) and until now been having no bother with my pushes. I have since started a new web app on my azure account and am having this same RPC failed issue that I saw previously. This is strange since I have been successfully pushing from the same wifi to my first project.

Comment: Did you try the GitHub test suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: You were right to have me try that. It also didn't push to github so I ended up setting up the ethernet and that fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a similar post, see [Github Push Error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489813/github-push-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-413)

the solution was to either reconfigure your webserver or to switch protocol (push via ssh instead of https).

You might want to try one of these solutions...

Comment: Azure Web Apps does not support SSH Git pushing. Thanks though.