# Git push failed : RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413

Tags: git

We are using gerrit for git repos.I am trying to push  existing project into a new repository (data size : 264MB) .I followed the below steps :

```
>cd <project/path>
>git init
>git remote add origin ssh://<user>@xxxxx:29418/<project>
>git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
>git push --all
```

But, it is giving me errors on git push

```
C:\xxxxxxxx>git push --all
Counting objects: 14174, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13610/13610), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 411 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 411 Length
Required
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (14174/14174), 39.95 MiB | 2.65 MiB/s, done.
Total 14174 (delta 3464), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

EDIT : We tried git config http.postBuffer 524288000 to resolve the issue but we are getting the same error

Comment: Resolution here - https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-282988530.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Push Error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489813/github-push-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-413)

Answer (score 0):

Topic has been discussed

[Github Push Error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489813/github-push-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-413)