# 413 Request Entity Too Large - Arcanist review

Tags: git, version-control, phabricator, arcanist

I am seeing below exception while executing `arc diff` to raise the Phabricator review. Changes are not big and it contains only 2 new files.

How do I get rid of it? Anyone tackled this in the past, please advise.

```
Exception
[HTTP/413] 
<html>
<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
<hr><center>Shield</center>
</body>
</html>
(Run with `--trace` for a full exception trace.)
```

Comment: have you solved the problem by changing the values of these parameters?

Comment: You can test it and work for me. for detail:https://stackoverflow.com/a/7707462/6636122

Answer (score 1):

If your server is Nginx, you can try to modify `client_max_body_size` bigger in nginx.conf file.

And if your server is Apache, you can try to modify `LimitRequestBody` bigger in \conf.d\php.conf.

Also please check the `php.ini` file, make sure the value of  `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` similar with server. After re-config, please reload it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to fix it [here](https://medium.com/@svsh227/error-413-request-entity-too-large-in-nginx-with-client-max-body-size-changes-in-nginx-6aacd525fe11)

---

This is happening because of your nginx server not allow to upload file which is larger than defined size in nginx config file.To solve it , you have to modify your nginx configuration. **So, if you are using Nginx:**

1. **Connect to your nginx server with your terminal.**
   Ex: `ssh -i pemFile.pem username@11.108.349.88 -v`
2. **Go to the config location and open it:** `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
3. **Search for this variable: client_max_body_size.** If you find it, just increase its size to 100M,
   If it doesn’t exist, then you can add below code inside and at the end of http: `client_max_body_size 100M;`
4. **Save this file.** ( If you want to save the changes you’ve made, press Control + O . To exit nano, type Control + X . If you ask nano to exit from a modified file, it will ask you if you want to save it.)
5. **Restart nginx to apply the changes.** `sudo service nginx restart`

Done