# Git error: RPC failed; HTTP 413 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: git

I got the `413 Request Entity Too Large` error after running this command:

```
git push -u test1 current-repo --force
```

[image]

What is a reason of this error? How to avoid this error?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question accordingly.

Comment: @VivekBhatt This can help you: [413 “Request Entity Too Large” error with uploading a file](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/2328) & [Large artifacts fail to upload](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3812)

Comment: But I am using github.

Comment: Please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489813/github-push-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-413

Comment: In my case, we have a reverse proxy in front of GitLab, and the proxy has a small default size.  Once we change that, all worked fine.

Comment: See this answer for the solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60833201/1226748

Answer (score 21):

Guess you have a reverse proxy like Nginx configured. That by default is limited to a 10m upload size. Check out http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size for how to configure your proxy.

Comment: Just need to add `client_max_body_size 100m;` at `location /` ... section in the config file.

Comment: Worked for me at 500m for a commit of 11.6gb. Thanks @M.Rostami

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after deleting the whole repository.And committing all files to the repository.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  In my case I'm trying a first push (1.3GB compressed) into an empty repository.

Comment: How did you get how big your first push was?

Answer (score -10):

I fixed this issue for me by deleting the ".git" folder and adding the large folder into .gitignore and starting over from the init.

Comment: that´s not a solution