# Gitlab error push files 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a problem with GIT when I attempt to push my files, this is what happens :

```
$ git push -u origin dev
Counting objects: 586, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (506/506), done.
Writing objects: 100% (586/586), 36.81 MiB | 1.58 MiB/s, done.
Total 586 (delta 267), reused 40 (delta 29)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 413 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 413 Request Entity Too Large
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I've already done :

`git config http.postBuffer 524288000`,

so that doesn't solve my poblem !
I found that the solution is to modify nginx config but am not using nginx .. I am working on Windows 10 and I don't see **where should I increase the value of `client_max_body_size`** !! 
Have you any idea about this problem on windows ?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize ?

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using IIS 7!

Comment: This is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489813/github-push-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-413

Comment: See this answer for the solution for this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60833201/1226748

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Push Error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489813/github-push-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-413)

Answer (score 8):

You got this error because the size limit on GitLab side is too low.

Login to GitLab with admin account and change these below values under Settings / General / Account and limit:

- Maximum attachment size (MB)
- Maximum import size (MB)

and save changes. It will fix this issue.