# how to fix it? git gitlab

Tags: gitlab, git-lfs

```
Locking support detected on remote "origin". Consider enabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://202.nl84.seedit4.me/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/info/lfs.locksverify true
Uploading LFS objects:  98% (681/697), 8.2 GB | 2.3 MB/s                                                                                                                                                           
Uploading LFS objects:  98% (681/697), 8.2 GB | 2.3 MB/s                                                                                                                                                           
Uploading LFS objects:  98% (681/697), 8.2 GB | 2.1 MB/s                                                                                                                                                           
Uploading LFS objects:  98% (681/697), 8.2 GB | 2.1 MB/s                                                                                                                                                           
Uploading LFS objects:  98% (681/697), 8.1 GB | 1.9 MB/s, done.                                                                                                                                                    
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=202.nl84.seedit4.me) %!!(string=/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/fb663f1b4d91384adc5ac8fdb9af1913518ff0a13480bcabec9b9a7a2711ac35/174103539) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=202.nl84.seedit4.me) %!!(string=/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/b20873242a22c81fe3ec6fa9b7e9cf807d879e41a275e4628e2953da4d36d283/129084241) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=202.nl84.seedit4.me) %!!(string=/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/4278efaee7fcc070a4d79bfacfd4b7021a06e6eb85ef249b030e4a6c91245eee/129524737) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=202.nl84.seedit4.me) %!!(string=/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/5a45fe82998b215eefe26ba7e42739046a5bf0b3820926415cf9cecc5b34c4ac/140182884) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=202.nl84.seedit4.me) %!!(string=/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/a59f68b7b00808383f9d56ed614cb12c9e7a37ab33826035442c55e0765096fd/164722834) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=202.nl84.seedit4.me) %!!(string=/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/6203e31bf4abadae7e82459bd95e010d004a50921a24b69d433e1cce29a8c4b3/259587134) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=202.nl84.seedit4.me) %!!(string=/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/3cdf5db943a06de4c527fda4537eb4e518156653bbfe0d665c2c0d2f9c539904/128242012) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=202.nl84.seedit4.me) %!!(string=/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/2db72b0121456b6c6e9f16d537661d5798b74376af9e40bf81bae91369c5661b/130354900) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=202.nl84.seedit4.me) %!!(string=/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/e5cd60ba3ed2830daf1c5aa0e6a340e60f4e119c3b686f7aa432e5dc9ad9825f/131075284) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=202.nl84.seedit4.me) %!!(string=/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/f5ec3e90720fb3f363ea4a935c5f5ea2525fe7b464ad6229492d1a8438b57d0b/119885784) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=202.nl84.seedit4.me) %!!(string=/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/4019cd76813f24725ceddaea04c07e799975896ee95e371c4b7e57736e1ccb5d/107303384) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://202.nl84.seedit4.me/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git'
MUSIC@DEVs-MacBook-Air ManySTLsDataSet % git push
Locking support detected on remote "origin". Consider enabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://202.nl84.seedit4.me/gitlab/STC/ManySTLsDataSet.git/info/lfs.locksverify true
Uploading LFS objects:  98% (681/697), 8.3 GB | 1.6 MB/s
```

```
$ watch df -h

Every 2.0s: df -h                                                                                                                                                                 CT14586: Wed Feb 23 05:10:07 2022

Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tank/subvol-14586-disk-0   50G  8.0G   43G  16% /
tank/userdata/14586       3.0T  2.6T  382G  88% /home
none                      492K  4.0K  488K   1% /dev
udev                       32G     0   32G   0% /dev/fuse
tmpfs                      32G   36K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      32G   12M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                      32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                     6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

it gets to the 82% quickly and then freezes. I feel like I need to check files with python script, for being only Cyrillic or UTF-8 or space or letters.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you asked the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71231259/git-lfs-cant-push -- please update your other question instead of asking the same question twice.

Comment: it doesn't tho. Do you any idea why git push may fail?

Comment: fix was to use SSH instead