# git show writing 100% but still show fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly and RPC failed error

Tags: git, fatal-error

I clone the project from git, do changes in it and then commit it and my changes showing on git.

Now after some minutes I again do the same process but it is showing this message:

"warning: redirecting to https://git.myCompanyname.io/projDirectory/project-ios.git/
Counting objects: 40, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 413 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 413 Request Entity Too Large
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date"

I am writing these commands:

cd - my project folder url
git init
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push -u origin master

Can any one suggest me where I am not correct.

Thanks

Comment: This looks more like a configuration issue with your  server. You should investigate the web server you run on  `https://git.myCompanyname.io/`  and tell us more about that and how it's configured related to git.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out that issue, please try !!! Of course I would right after I hit post!

I had the repo set to use the HTTPS url, I changed it to the SSH address, and everything resumed working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489813/github-push-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-413) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize)

The problem could also be a result of Unavailable network Connection. We have that kind of problem, remember Chandni